# Toggle Menu list items display

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a menu that I want to drop down when you click on the hamburger icon. The list items show up after the button is clicked, but is still seen when the button is not clicked. I can't figure out how to hide the menu.

I have the code here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/aWZYGJ)

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
     if (x.className === "topnav") {
         x.className += " responsive";
     } else {
         x.className = "topnav";
     }
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-icon3').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

.header {
 background-color: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 7%;
 height: 80px;
}

h1 {
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 margin-top: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 color: #D18E8F;
}

#nav-icon {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 7%;
 margin-top: 8px;
 /*padding-right: 1%;*/
 float: right;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #8c8c8c;
 border-radius: 6px;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2), #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
 top: 10px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 20px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 10px;
 width: 0%;
 left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 10px;
 width: 0%;
 left: 50%;
}

.topnav.responsive {
 /*display: none;*/
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 height: 160px;
}

ul.topnav.responsive {
 list-style: none;
 font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
 float: left;
 margin-left: 7%;
 /*padding-left: 2%;*/
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 85%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li {
 padding-top: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a:hover {
 color: #7EBEA3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <title>Gabriella Farfan</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Gabriella Farfan</h1>
   <div id="nav-icon">
    <div id="nav-icon3">
     <a id="nav-icon3" onclick="myFunction();">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
     </a>
    </div> 
   </div>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="About.html">About Me</a>
   </li>
   <li style="border-bottom: none">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
  
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.topnav { display: none; }` and `.topnav.responsive { display: block; }` and your code will work fine.

```
.topnav {
  display: none;
}

.topnav.responsive {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  height: 160px;
}
```

You can also add this for make full hamburger clickable (not only line).

```
#nav-icon3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

Working fork of your code: [Сodepen](https://codepen.io/lenevro/pen/qmNgMd)

Answer (score 0):

I have made this little fix. Hope it helps.

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.header {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 7%;
    height: 80px;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #D18E8F;
}

#nav-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 7%;
    margin-top: 8px;
    /*padding-right: 1%;*/
    float: right;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #8c8c8c;
    border-radius: 6px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2), #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 10px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 20px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
}

.responsive {
    /*display: none;*/

    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    height: 160px;
}

ul.responsive {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7%;
    /*padding-left: 2%;*/
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 85%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.responsive li {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

ul.responsive li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8c8c8c;
}

ul.responsive li a:hover {
    color: #7EBEA3;
}

.topnav{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className = " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.